# What is the fastest way to update all values in an Erlang ETS table?

Tags: performance, erlang, ets

I would like to apply a function to all the tuples in an ETS table :

The table is a set, each key appears only once.

My table contains only tuples of the same type:

```
{Key, X, Y, VX, VY}
```

All values are `::integer()`

What i want to do is have a certain value Elapsed and update all
my tuples with a function `apply_vector/2`

```
apply_vector({K, X, Y, 0, 0}, _Elapsed) ->
    {K, X, Y, 0, 0};

apply_vector({K, X, Y, VX, VY}, Elapsed) ->
    NewX = X + (VX * Elapsed),
    NewY = Y + (VY * Elapsed),
    {K, NewX, NewY, VX, VY}.
```

#### Possible solutions

- If i use `ets:foldl`, my inserts could be traversed during the fold, and
  result in an infinite (very long) loop.
- I could prepare the new tuples with a `ets:foldl`, and then insert the whole
  list.
- I could insert to a new table, then replace the old table by the new,
  but i don't want to limit access to the table with calls to a
  gen_server, the table must be accessible at any time.
- I can not use `ets:update_element` because I need to read VX and VY values
  to update X and Y.
- I know there are some iterators utilities but no one seems to allow to
  pass a fun.

I need to make this update every 1 - 5 seconds. So, wich solution is
the most efficient with 10 tuples ? With 100 tuples ? With more ?

Thank You !

I Keep a list of boats, the Key is the Boat ID, X and Y are geographic
coordinates, VX and VY represents a vector of movement: a deplacement
for one second. Elapsed is a ratio, a number of seconds since the last
update. The table helps to know at any time the position of each boat.

Comment: With 100 tuples you won't have any performance issue at all.

Comment: Yes my question is badly asked, say 10 000 or 100 000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably use ets:foldl for this.

Seems to me like you only need iterative access on this data. So you could just use list of records here.

Another approach (which I would go for) is to put a boat supervisor and create a gen_server for every boat. That way every boat will have its own state and you won't actually need to traverse any list.

Also checkout qlc http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/qlc.html
qlc let's you use list comrehensions on ets or mnesia tables. It will probably have the same performance as foldl though.

Comment: I need to access to data in a 'classic' way yoo. That's why i want to update positions every X seconds, because data needs to be up to date at any time. (but with soft precision : a few seconds is not a problem)

Comment: So, i already had a process for each boat but i shutdown them when they are idle. As they move, i don't consider them as idle no more, and they sent updates to the table every X seconds. So, answer accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no great way to do what you are doing.

Recently, I ran in to a similar issue (Updating ~5000 rows, once a second)

Which led me to just take a totally different approach.
So, do you NEED to store the interpreted value?  Or can you compute the value upon lookup?

How about storing:
{K,X,Y,VX,VY,LastUpdateTime}

And then doing something like (uncompilable example):

```
boats:get_all() -> % Record syntax would be smarter here, but it's an example...
  ets:foldl(?TABLE,[],fun(Row={Id,_,_,_,_,_},Acc) -> [{Id,calc(Row)}|Acc] end).

boats:get(Id) ->
  [Row] = ets:lookup(?TABLE,Id),
  calc(Row).

calc({_K,X,Y,VX,VY,LastUpdate}) ->
  {X + (VX * (now() - LastUpdate)), Y + (VY * (now() - LastUpdate)}
```

This allows you not to block on a genserver, but also not to have to update the table every 5 seconds.  You'd basically only update the table every time a boat reports in.

Comment: Good point. I have several gui maps on which i want to display the boats in real time, so i often need *all* the values. But i can launch the procedure less often and store the LastUpdate timestamp as you've said, so a process which lookup a value can update the value until now.

Comment: FInally I'm using your solution. I only update one row at a time : when a vector changes, i compute the position according to the old X,Y, the old vector and the last update time, then I store the new vector. The client maps (javascript) receive the full table on page load, and then I push only vector changes to the clients when written to the tables. The client has last -update-time, vectors and known position so it can compute the position in real time. Unfortunately I keep the original accepted answer because the question was "about updating an entire ETS table. But thank you very much